# Isomorphism on top homology for closed, orientable manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

If $M$ and $N$ are orientable, closed $n$-manifolds, then $H_n(M)$ and $H_n(N)$ are generated by the fundamental classes $[M]$ and $[N]$. We can think of them as the sum of the faces of triangulations of $M$ and $N$. My question is the following: is a map $f:M \to N$ that induces an isomorphism on $H_n$ necessarily surjective? Since the image $f_*([M])$ must generate $H_n(M)$, then it seems that we can view $f_*([M])$ as a triangulation of $N$, so $f$ must be surjective. I'm having trouble making this rigorous, but is the idea even correct?

Thanks!

Edit: does this interpretation of $[M], [N]$ also give that every orientable, closed manifold is triangulable?

Comment: Probably you mean "compact" as otherwise the top homology might be zero..

Comment: Well, by "closed" I mean compact and without boundary.

Comment: Nitpick: I know we were all assuming it, but $M$ and $N$ need to be connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is correct, but the proof is sketchy. You should try to show that $H_n$ of $N$ minus a point vanishes.

Not every closed orientable manifold is triangulable; for example, the [$E_8$ manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_manifold) is a 4-dimensional counterexample. That interpretation of the fundamental class is only correct if a triangulation exists.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand the difference between a triangulation of $M$ and an $n$-chain corresponding to $[M]$. If $\sum_i \sigma_i$ is an $n$-chain corresponding to $[M]$, each face of $\sigma_i$ is the face of exactly one $\sigma_j$, $i\neq j$. Why doesn't this determine a triangulation of $M$?

Comment: @William: well, first, a singular $n$-chain only involves singular $n$-simplices, so it can't be enough data to determine a triangulation because it doesn't include any information about simplices of lower dimension.